# Declaring event in user control asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have declared a event on my user control

```
public event EventHandler<AddressEventArgs> SaveButtonClick; 

protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (SaveButtonClick != null) 
  { 
    SaveButtonClick(this, new AddressEventArgs) ; 

  } 
}
```

After I have  added the user control to the new page, how would I trap the 
event raised by the user control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you can `[Browsable]` property on the event, or you can imperatively bind to the events.

```
userControl.SaveButtonClick += new EventHandler(handlerFunctionName);

public void handlerFunctionName(AddressEventArgs args)
{
     // Here, you have access to args in response the the event of your user control
}
```

Comment: thanks saeed .can you give me some insight on the [browsable] property.

Comment: Browsable property simply means that this attribute/event should be accessible in design-time environments. They are Properties window, Markup and code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
Control.SaveButtonClick += controlClicked;

protected void controlClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   //Do work
}
```

First you need to subscribe to your event, and give it a method to call when the event is raised.